# how can I make getaddrinfo return only one result?

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming, getaddrinfo

I want to use getaddrinfo() but get only the first result.

more specifically, I want the function to first scan the hosts file and fetch the first result found, and only if not found in hosts I want to query the dns server.

is it possible?

thanks.

Comment: querying dns if not found in the hosts file should be the default behavior on most operating systems, what kind of setup/operating system are you on ?

Comment: Have you seen http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/gethostent.html? (gethostent and friends)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order on how resolving hosts is done is define in [`/etc/host.conf`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/host.conf.5.html) using the keyword `order`:

> *order*
>
> This keyword specifies how host lookups are to be performed.
>                 It should be followed by one or more lookup methods, separated
>                 by commas.  Valid methods are *bind*, *hosts*, and *nis*.

However I doubt you can restrict the number of results to `1` per this configuration directly.

Answer (score 4):

You can't. It behaves as documented. You only have to *use* one result: that's up to you.